# counting the number of non-zero numbers in a column of a df in pandas/python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a df that looks something like:

`a b c d e  0 1 2 3 5 1 4 0 5 2 5 8 9 6 0  4 5 0 0 0`

I would like to output the number of numbers in column c that are not zero.

Comment: I saw that, thanks. Unfortunately their question is different because they want it for each row, and to be divided by the sum, so none of the code that was used there is applicable to my question.

Comment: The first line of the top answer there reads "To count nonzero values, just do `(column!=0).sum()`, where `column` is the data you want to do it for." That seems to be exactly what you're asking ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use double [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  0  1  2  3  5
1  1  4  0  5  2
2  5  8  9  6  0
3  4  5  0  0  0

print (df != 0).sum(1)
0    4
1    4
2    4
3    2
dtype: int64

print (df != 0).sum(1).sum()
14
```

If you need count only column `c` or `d`:

```
print (df['c'] != 0).sum()
2

print (df['d'] != 0).sum()
3
```

EDIT: Solution with [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
print ((df != 0).values.sum())
14
```

Comment: That makes sense, but how do I do it just for column c? I don't want the total number.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy's `count_nonzero` function is efficient for this.

`np.count_nonzero(df["c"])`